# Can a woman take the deeksha for mudra (applied on daily basis just like men - but only on hands and face) after or before menopause?

Tags: vaishnavism, women, madhvacharya, initiation

Can a woman take the deeksha for Thaptha mudra after menopause?

Comment: You mean diksha? So this diksha is not available for women of all ages?

Comment: I am not sure, few people say that -above 40+ women take diksha

Comment: Just curious, what are all the symbols added in this rituals besides the conch and discus? Where are they added? Do you know? For the ritual of the Sri Vaishnavas, there is no age or gender restriction.

Comment: If Madhavas follow Pancharatra then I don't think there are any of such restrictions because pancharatra allows everyone and anyone to be initiated (if he/she is not in ashoucha includes masika ashucha for women).

Comment: If that is the case, I don't see all madhwa women applying it. There must be some restriction or rules to follow